# Escaping Unicode string in XmlElement despite writing XML in UTF-8

Tags: c#, .net, xml, unicode, xml-serialization

For a given `XmlElement`, I need to be able to set the inner text to an escaped version of the Unicode string, despite the document ultimately being encoded in UTF-8. Is there any way of achieving this?

Here's a simple version of the code:

```
const string text = "&#xF1;";

var document = new XmlDocument {PreserveWhitespace = true};
var root = document.CreateElement("root");
root.InnerXml = text;
document.AppendChild(root);

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, OmitXmlDeclaration = true};
using (var stream = new FileStream("out.xml", FileMode.Create))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    document.WriteTo(writer);
```

Expected:

```
<root>&#xF1;</root>
```

Actual:

```
<root>ñ</root>
```

Using an `XmlWriter` directly and calling `WriteRaw(text)` works, but I only have access to an `XmlDocument`, and the serialization happens later. On the `XmlElement`, `InnerText` escapes the `&` to `&amp;`, as expected, and setting `Value` throws an exception.

Is there some way of setting the inner text of an `XmlElement` to the escaped ASCII text, regardless of the encoding that is ultimately used? I feel like I must be missing something obvious, or it's just not possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask XmlWriter to produce ASCII output, it should give you character references for all non-ASCII content.

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {Encoding = Encoding.ASCII, OmitXmlDeclaration = true};
```

The output is still valid UTF-8, because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, but then the file encoding will be ASCII. What I need is for the file to still be encoded in UTF-8, but the contents of this element only to be escaped as if the encoding was ASCII. The requirement is strange, I know, since it's not necessary to do so if the file is UTF-8.

Comment: The *file encoding* will be UTF-8, because with the XML Declaration omitted that's what it'll default to. It's still valid to encode any character to a reference in a UTF-8 file, and any compliant XML parser will have no problems. If the (curious) requirement is that some elements contain raw text and other contain character references, then you will have to serialise them as separate fragments.