# How to write ISO code accent in XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, diacritics

I would like to write Latin accents inside an XML text file with the corresponding ISO code.
For instance `é` is replaced by `&#233;` on the file.
My issue is my first & is escaped by **Xml.Linq**.
So the result is `&#amp;233;`.

```
internal void SaveCurrentFile(XElement root)
{
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
        Encoding = encoding
    };
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(GetFolderPath() + "test.xml", xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        root.Save(writer);
    }
}
```

I did not see any options in XmlWriterSettings to help me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't actually need to do anything.  Just write the character normally and make sure to use UTF8.

Comment: You could write with `Encoding.ASCII`.  If you do, all non-ASCII Unicode characters will get escaped as shown in [Escaping unicode string in XmlElement despite writing XML in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18006146/3744182).

Comment: I could not use UTF8 (due to personal restrictions) but with the ASCII encoding it looks good.
Thank you!

Comment: How does this restriction arise? XML text is Unicode characters, regardless of the document encoding.

Comment: The XML files is consumes by a game. I cannot control how it reads it and I already tried to give Utf8 files and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric character entity references are Unicode codepoints. For example,
&#x1f6b2; for  (U+1F6B2). &#233; would be é (U+00E9). Numeric character entity references are typically used only when the document encoding doesn't support a particular Unicode codepoint. An XML writer takes care of this for you.

So if you want é to be emitted as numeric character entity, you just have to use a document encoding that doesn't support it. ASCII is one. However, it will probably be in hexadecimal (&#xE9;) rather than decimal (&#233;).

Comment: That is correct. I have seen that the input is (&#xE9;) but it is fine for me in hexadecimal too.